# Why won't my alert box appear in my Javascript/HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently writing a very simple webpage to calculate GPA.  I am utilizing a form and then using Javascript to use two functions to calculate and show the final GPA.

I might have done the functions incorrectly, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  When I hit the "Calculate" button, the alert box I programmed does not appear.

```js
var gradeCredit = {
  "A": 4.0,
  "A-": 3.67,
  "B+": 3.33,
  "B": 3.0,
  "B-": 2.67,
  "C+": 2.33,
  "C": 2.0,
  "C-": 1.67,
  "D": 1.0,
  "F": 0
}
var calcGrade = function() {
  grade1 = document.form.grade1.value;
  grade2 = document.form.grade2.value;
  grade3 = document.form.grade3.value;
  grade4 = document.form.grade4.value;
  grade5 = document.form.grade5.value;
  grade6 = document.form.grade6.value;
  finalGPA = ((gradeCredit[grade1] + gradeCredit[grade2] + gradeCredit[grade3] + gradeCredit[grade4] + gradeCredit[grade5] + gradeCredit[grade6]) / 6);
  alert("GPA =  " + finalGPA)
}
```

```html
    <CENTER>
        <form Name="GPAForm">
        <table border=3 bgcolor=#ff9999 CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="2">
            <TH></TH>
            <TH>Class 1</TH>
            <TH>Class 2</TH>
            <TH>Class 3</TH>
            <TH>Class 4</TH>
            <TH>Class 5</TH>
            <TH>Class 6</TH>
    
            <TR>
            <TD>Grade</TD>
            <TD><input type=text size=5 name="grade1" ALIGN=TOP MAXLENGTH=5></TD>
            <TD><input type=text size=5 name="grade2" ALIGN=TOP MAXLENGTH=5></TD>
            <TD><input type=text size=5 name="grade3" ALIGN=TOP MAXLENGTH=5></TD>
            <TD><input type=text size=5 name="grade4" ALIGN=TOP MAXLENGTH=5></TD>
            <TD><input type=text size=5 name="grade5" ALIGN=TOP MAXLENGTH=5></TD>
            <TD><input type=text size=5 name="grade6" ALIGN=TOP MAXLENGTH=5></TD>
                
                    
           <TR ALIGN=CENTER>
           <TD colspan=7> <input type="button" VALUE="Calculate Your GPA!" name ="calc" OnClick="calcGrade()">
           </TD>
           </TR>
           </TABLE>
           </FORM>
           <BR>
           <P>
                    
           <P>
           </CENTER>
```

Comment: Inplace of form use GPAForm like this document.GPAForm.grade1.value

Comment: document.forms[0] would also work, but i think you shouldn't use this code mainly because most of it deprecated and both html and js evolved since this piece of code first written...

Comment: Note that your html contains a lot of obsolete elements and attributes

Answer (score 2):

See the working code here : https://jsfiddle.net/y8fb9ctd/

```
    <form name="GPAForm">
    <table border=3 bgcolor=#ff9999 CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="2">
        <TH></TH>
        <TH>Class 1</TH>
        <TH>Class 2</TH>
        <TH>Class 3</TH>
        <TH>Class 4</TH>
        <TH>Class 5</TH>
        <TH>Class 6</TH>

        <TR>
        <TD>Grade</TD>
        <TD><input type=text size=5 name="grade1" ALIGN=TOP MAXLENGTH=5></TD>
        <TD><input type=text size=5 name="grade2" ALIGN=TOP MAXLENGTH=5></TD>
        <TD><input type=text size=5 name="grade3" ALIGN=TOP MAXLENGTH=5></TD>
        <TD><input type=text size=5 name="grade4" ALIGN=TOP MAXLENGTH=5></TD>
        <TD><input type=text size=5 name="grade5" ALIGN=TOP MAXLENGTH=5></TD>
        <TD><input type=text size=5 name="grade6" ALIGN=TOP MAXLENGTH=5></TD>

       </TR>

       <TR ALIGN=CENTER>
       <TD colspan=7> <input type="button" VALUE="Calculate Your GPA!" name ="calc" OnClick="calcGrade()">
       </TD>
       </TR>
       </table>
       </form>
       <BR>

       <script>

           var gradeCredit = {
                "A": 4.0,
                "A-": 3.67,
                "B+": 3.33,
                "B": 3.0,
                "B-": 2.67,
                "C+": 2.33,
                "C": 2.0,
                "C-": 1.67,
                "D": 1.0,
                "F": 0
            }

            var calcGrade = function() {
                grade1 = document.GPAForm.grade1.value;
                grade2 = document.GPAForm.grade2.value;
                grade3 = document.GPAForm.grade3.value;
                grade4 = document.GPAForm.grade4.value;
                grade5 = document.GPAForm.grade5.value;
                grade6 = document.GPAForm.grade6.value;
                finalGPA = ((gradeCredit[grade1] + gradeCredit[grade2] + gradeCredit[grade3] + gradeCredit[grade4] + gradeCredit[grade5] + gradeCredit[grade6]) / 6);
                alert("GPA =  " + finalGPA)
            }

            </script>
```

From your code, there are multiple issues

> The main problem is

- Use `document.GPAForm.` since it is the name of the form
- do not use `LANGUAGE=javascript`, keep `<script>` or use `<script type="text/javascript" >`

> Other minor problems

- `<CENTER>` html tag has been deprecated
- `ALIGN=CENTER` attribute has also been deprecated

use CSS for styling to fix above two codesmells

- The TR tag before "ALIGN=CENTER" was missing a closing tag

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**
You can access the form by its name `document.GPAForm`.
And you should remove invalid inputs from the sum, otherwise it will be `NaN` (ideally you should also cast the input to uppercase letters).

```html
<CENTER>
  <form Name="GPAForm">
    <table border=3 bgcolor=#ff9999 CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="2">
      <TH></TH>
      <TH>Class 1</TH>
      <TH>Class 2</TH>
      <TH>Class 3</TH>
      <TH>Class 4</TH>
      <TH>Class 5</TH>
      <TH>Class 6</TH>

      <TR>
        <TD>Grade</TD>
        <TD><input type=text size=5 name="grade1" ALIGN=TOP MAXLENGTH=5></TD>
        <TD><input type=text size=5 name="grade2" ALIGN=TOP MAXLENGTH=5></TD>
        <TD><input type=text size=5 name="grade3" ALIGN=TOP MAXLENGTH=5></TD>
        <TD><input type=text size=5 name="grade4" ALIGN=TOP MAXLENGTH=5></TD>
        <TD><input type=text size=5 name="grade5" ALIGN=TOP MAXLENGTH=5></TD>
        <TD><input type=text size=5 name="grade6" ALIGN=TOP MAXLENGTH=5></TD>


        <TR ALIGN=CENTER>
          <TD colspan=7> <input type="button" VALUE="Calculate Your GPA!" name="calc" OnClick="calcGrade()">
          </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
  </FORM>
  <BR>
  <P>

    <P>
</CENTER>


<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
  var gradeCredit = {
    "A": 4.0,
    "A-": 3.67,
    "B+": 3.33,
    "B": 3.0,
    "B-": 2.67,
    "C+": 2.33,
    "C": 2.0,
    "C-": 1.67,
    "D": 1.0,
    "F": 0
  }

  var calcGrade = function() {
  // You can access the form by its name
    var grade1 = document.GPAForm.grade1.value;
    var grade2 = document.GPAForm.grade2.value;
    var grade3 = document.GPAForm.grade3.value;
    var grade4 = document.GPAForm.grade4.value;
    var grade5 = document.GPAForm.grade5.value;
    var grade6 = document.GPAForm.grade6.value;
    
    // You should remove invalid inputs from the sum
    // Ideally you should also cast the letters to uppercase letters
    var finalGPA = gradeCredit[grade1] || 0
      + gradeCredit[grade2] || 0
      + gradeCredit[grade3] || 0
      + gradeCredit[grade4] || 0
      + gradeCredit[grade5] || 0
      + gradeCredit[grade6] || 0
      
    finalGPA = finalGPA / 6;
    alert("GPA =  " + finalGPA)
  }
</script>

</main>
```

Comment: Also, that's a very old-style html !

Comment: @Ivar An easy game of "spot the differences", since I commented the changes I made in the code. But I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

This could be way more complicated than you are looking for, but for some reason your question inspired me. I changed your input boxes into dropdowns so that the user cannot accidentally enter a value that you don't want. Also added error catching in case someone clicks te calculate button but didn't enter any grades.

```js
var GPA = document.GPAForm;
document.getElementById("calc").addEventListener("click", function() {
 var num = 0;
 var den = 0;
  var dropdowns = GPA.getElementsByTagName("select");
  for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
   if (dropdowns[i].value != "") {
     num += Number(dropdowns[i].value);
      den += 1;
    }
  }
  if (den === 0) {
   alert("Please enter at least one grade.")
  } else {
   alert("GPA =  " + (num/den).toFixed(2));
  }  
})
```

```css
table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<form Name="GPAForm">
  <table border=3 bgcolor=#ff9999 CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="2">
    <tr>
      <TH></TH>
      <TH>Class 1</TH>
      <TH>Class 2</TH>
      <TH>Class 3</TH>
      <TH>Class 4</TH>
      <TH>Class 5</TH>
      <TH>Class 6</TH>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <TD>Grade</TD>
      <TD><select name="grade1">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="4">A</option>
        <option value="3.67">A-</option>
        <option value="3.33">B+</option>
        <option value="3">B</option>
        <option value="2.67">B-</option>
        <option value="2.33">C+</option>
        <option value="2">C</option>
        <option value="1.67">C-</option>
        <option value="1">D</option>
        <option value="0">F</option>
      </select></TD>
      <TD><select name="grade2">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="4">A</option>
        <option value="3.67">A-</option>
        <option value="3.33">B+</option>
        <option value="3">B</option>
        <option value="2.67">B-</option>
        <option value="2.33">C+</option>
        <option value="2">C</option>
        <option value="1.67">C-</option>
        <option value="1">D</option>
        <option value="0">F</option>
      </select></TD>
      <TD><select name="grade3">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="4">A</option>
        <option value="3.67">A-</option>
        <option value="3.33">B+</option>
        <option value="3">B</option>
        <option value="2.67">B-</option>
        <option value="2.33">C+</option>
        <option value="2">C</option>
        <option value="1.67">C-</option>
        <option value="1">D</option>
        <option value="0">F</option>
      </select></TD>
      <TD><select name="grade4">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="4">A</option>
        <option value="3.67">A-</option>
        <option value="3.33">B+</option>
        <option value="3">B</option>
        <option value="2.67">B-</option>
        <option value="2.33">C+</option>
        <option value="2">C</option>
        <option value="1.67">C-</option>
        <option value="1">D</option>
        <option value="0">F</option>
      </select></TD>
      <TD><select name="grade5">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="4">A</option>
        <option value="3.67">A-</option>
        <option value="3.33">B+</option>
        <option value="3">B</option>
        <option value="2.67">B-</option>
        <option value="2.33">C+</option>
        <option value="2">C</option>
        <option value="1.67">C-</option>
        <option value="1">D</option>
        <option value="0">F</option>
      </select></TD>
      <TD><select name="grade6">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="4">A</option>
        <option value="3.667">A-</option>
        <option value="3.333">B+</option>
        <option value="3">B</option>
        <option value="2.667">B-</option>
        <option value="2.333">C+</option>
        <option value="2">C</option>
        <option value="1.667">C-</option>
        <option value="1">D</option>
        <option value="0">F</option>
      </select></TD>
    </tr>
    <tr ALIGN=CENTER>
      <TD colspan=7> <input type="button" VALUE="Calculate Your GPA!" id ="calc"></TD>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```